# C# How to to indicate relationship between properties to the user of a class?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class House
{
    public string Address {get; set;}

    private int _numberOfBedrooms;
    public int NumberOfBedrooms 
    {
        get { return _numberOfBedrooms; }
        set 
        {
            _numberOfBedrooms = value;
            _groundPlanIsObsolete |= true;
        }
    }

    private int _numberOfBathrooms;
    public int NumberOfBathrooms 
    {
        get { return _numberOfBathrooms; }
        set 
        {
            _numberOfBathrooms = value;
            _groundPlanIsObsolete |= true;
        }
    }

   private bool _groundPlanIsObsolete;
   private myFloorPlan _groundPlan;
   public myFloorPlan GroundPlan 
   { get
     {
         if(_groundPlanIsObsolete)
             _groundPlan = new myFloorPlan(NumberOfBedrooms, NumberOfBathrooms);

         _groundPlanIsObsolete &= false;

         return _groundPlan;
     }
   }
}
```

`new myFloorPlan(NumberOfBedrooms, NumberOfBathrooms)` is a very lengthy function.
I want to call it as rarely as possible.

**Is this bad design?**

I don't like my current design, because from a user point of view, it is not clear, which properties will have an effect on `GroundPlan`.
This has two disadvantages:

1. If one of them is not set, and the user tries to get the `GroundPlan` I could throw an exception, but is there a "nicer" way to let him know before he makes the mistake?
2. I would like to encourage the user to make up his mind about the number of rooms before calling the `GroundPlan`, to prevent frequent computationally heavy updates.

**Should I indicate this?**

Or is this something that should be documented in the comment section of the properties?

And:

**How could I indicate this?**

Comment: I would say, return null when the properties are not valid, and check for null in the subscriber class of this. And in the top, add class summary to mention what is valid, to help developers remember. Add more comments in the properties as well.

Comment: As for asking user to make up his mind, that ain't a good idea. You can probably show an alert saying "this will take time. make sure you have correct number of rooms selected, before continuing". Other than that, you can always disable set methods, and create a constructor to set them first time. But then user will end up feeling frustrated, if he makes a typing mistake and can't change it later.

P.S. This question is best suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Side note. _groundPlanIsObsolete |= true < this is always true because anything | true === true. _groundPlanIsObsolete &= false < this is always false because of same reasons. So just use _groundPlanIsObsolete = true or _groundPlanIsObsolete = false.

Comment: Technically, it's the same thing, but I used `|= true` to express that if any of these properties have changed, the GroundPlan is obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `House` immutable and use proper encapsulation.

You can combine immutability with fluent syntax easily in C# to build your object:

```
House house = new House();

house = house.AddBedrooms(2);
```

Code for `House`:

```
class House
{
   int _numberOfBedrooms;

   public House()
   {
   }

   public House AddBedrooms(int numberOfBedroomsToAdd)
   {
      House house = new House();

      house._numberOfBedrooms = _numberOfBedrooms + numberOfBedroomsToAdd;

      return house;
   }

   //etc...
}
```

It's a bit more work, but it provides proper encapsulation. Putting getters/setters on domain objects is nasty. There are more advanced patterns which split the building of the object into a *builder* but the principle is the same. You could then use fluent syntax on your builder.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to encourage the user to make up his mind about the number of rooms before calling the GroundPlan, to prevent frequent computationally heavy updates.

I would recommend passing NumberOfBathrooms and NumberOfBedrooms through as parameters on the method, that way it's clear to the user what the dependencies are. Or, if you want to keep them as properties perhaps pass them through on the constructor and make the properties read only.